# jQuery synchronous ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my jquery code.

```
function getData(){
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data : {'action':'getDatas'},
        url: "ajax.php",
        success: function(response) {
        }   
    });
    return false;
}
```

When This Ajax request is fire then all ajax request is fir but not return any ajax whenever the first ajax is not finished.

no i used this code.

```
function getData(){
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data : {'action':'getDatas'},
        url: "ajax.php",
        success: function(response) {
        }   
    });
    return false;
}
```

When this ajax is fire then if this request is not finished then not fire any request. after finished this request the after all ajax request is fire.

please help i want to fire multiple request at a time without waiting any request finished.

thank you.

Comment: Not completely sure if you are looking for this.
$.ajax(type:"post",async:false,url:"ajax.php").done(function(data){after the request is successfully done}).fail(function(data){if the request failed}).always(function(data){will always be executed regardless of success or failure});

Comment: I think something wrong in you ajax.php page. Check its Status Code.

Comment: in ajax.php i write a query and return json array?

Comment: it's really not clear what problem is when you set `async:true`. Use browser console network tab to inspect requests and get clues as to what problems might be ( status, data sent, data received etc)

Comment: @charlietfl hey dear when this ajax is fire it respond after 2 minutes for collect all data. on those time i try to send any other request it pending.

Comment: can have more than one active request but 2 minutes is crazy...how much data is being pulled?